# Call https based Java service from .Net Client but have strange Exception

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf

I have a https Service, I Installed the certificate on my LOCAL machine and the server where my WSDL is.  Its in the Trusted Root Store.

I am trying to call a java based service from my .Net Unit Test.  But I am getting a weird exception that I am not sure how to solve...anyone ever seen this type of exception.

---

```
    System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=WSWS3227E:  Error: Exception:
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21379309?

Comment: Ahhh man I saw some links on this site about it but not this one exactly...Thanks!!!!